# Asking a question as a guest and then deleting it or editing it?

Tags: support, unregistered-users

I asked a question as a guest on a stackexchange site and because i used my gmail account it had my image in the post. I wanted to ask the question anonymously but now I can't delete it because i posted as a guest it doesn't recognize me even when i associate my email with that stack exchange site.

Is there a way to delete a guest post or remove the image associated with the guest post?

Comment: If it's matter of privacy, I'll go ask in chat, e.g. Tavern here on MSE, community manager can most likely change the associated email thus making the image disappear. Otherwise, flag the question and moderator can delete it. Editing won't really do any good as the problem is the avatar.

Answer (score 2):

Asking a question as a guest is more of a convenience thing than a privacy thing. Its never a good idea to ask a question that you don't *really* want associated with you without a good reason.

I'd definitely suggest you use use the contact us link, mention the two accounts and the post in question and request the question be *dissociated* (which I think is generally the worse option here) or deleted.

I do believe a moderator can change your avatar for that account or deleted the post as well, but if its an account you're unable to log in as - that gets messy, since we need to know you are genuine.  If you can prove you're both accounts I suppose it gets easier, but as a mod, I'd think VERY hard before touching something like that (and probably grab a passing CM for advice).